# Why is Thread Pool Executor giving me exceptions?

Tags: java, threadpool

I'm trying to parallelize some application code using Java 8 threads.   The `Runnable` to be executed is:

```
static private class Solver implements Runnable {
    int iQuery;
    Graph graph;
    int[] nodeSet;
    Solution solution;
    public Solver(int iQuery, Graph graph, int[] nodeSet, Solution solution) {
        this.iQuery = iQuery;...
    }
    public void run() {
        solution.results[ iQuery ] = solution.solve( graph, nodeSet );
    }
}
```

The code that tries to launch the threads is:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor =
    (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool( Math.min( nQueries,  8 ) );
for ( int iQuery = 0; iQuery < nQueries; iQuery++ ) {
    ...
    // FORMERLY:  solution.results[ iQuery ] = solution.solve( graph, nodeSet );
    executor.execute( new Solver( iQuery, graph, nodeSet, solution ) );
}
executor.shutdown();
for ( int result : solution.results ) 
    System.out.println( result );
```

I'm encountering several problems, however.  When I try running this code, I get lots of errors like the following:

[image]

Also, in trying to debug this, I set the size of the thread pool to 1; in this case, I don't get errors like the ones above, but the output is truncated in the sense that only the first part of the results is valid, as if the Executor had "stopped early"; in that case, adding a delay before the shutdown gives the correct results.

Where am I going astray?

Comment: Not enough code to tell.  Somewhere something is losing the rest of the trace.  Its probably somewhere in your code though.  Of what you posted, my guess would be that solution.results isn't big enough for iQuery elements.  Doing solution.results[x]= is a bit of a smell to begin with, you probably shouldn't be allowing direct access to Solution internals like that. And it's really weird to be doing solution.results[x] = solution.solve, rather than solution.solve writing the results directly.

Comment: Also, you do have one problem-  shutdown does not wait for all tasks to be finished.  So your second loop won't all have valid results.  If you want to block and wait for the results to print them out, use awaitTermination instead

Comment: @GabeSechan Not "instead". You have to call `awaitTermination()` "after" calling `shutdown()`.

Comment: @GabeSechan, @Andreas, the ```awaitTermination()``` works fine, thanks!   However, I'm dubious that it's a problem in the code, since it works fine for a pool of one thread.   I'll put a try/catch in my ```Runable``` and see whether that reveals anything.

Comment: I see now that my logic causes all the threads  to reference the same read/write variable, and maybe the collision when multiple threads try to write messes stuff up.